# Why do not you record an id in a table with a many-to-one relation? Spring Data, Liquidbase

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, liquibase

I can not figure out what the problem might be with the recording of id .
In what an essence: I create object "building" - I add in it an object "photo" and as a result I want to record in database an object a building (in which already there is a photo object).
The building is being recorded, the photo is also there, but the id of the building is not saved in the "photo" table. Why can it be?

Building Table 
[image: Building table:]Photo Table

[image: Photo Table]

```
@Entity
public class Building {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Photo> photos;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_building",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "building_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
            })
    private List<Category> categories;

    public Building() {
    }

    public Building(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Building(String name, String description, List<Photo> photos) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public Building(String name, String description, List<Photo> photos, List<Category> categories) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.photos = photos;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Photo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
    private Building building;
    @Column(name = "original_size")
    byte[] originalSize;
    @Column(name = "small_size")
    byte[] smallSize;
    @Column(name = "middle_size")
    byte[] middleSize;
    @Column(name = "large_size")
    byte[] largeSize;

    public Photo() {
    }

    public Photo(Building building, byte[] originalSize) {
        this.building = building;
        this.originalSize = originalSize;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I can not properly linked the tables? or what could be the reason?

Comment: Please, post some code where you save these entities.

Comment: @htshame i just using constructor Photo(Building building, byte[] originalSize) from create anonymous object- add to list and setting into building. 
 In result i use method save(buiding) BuidingDAO of Spring-Data